# Javascript | How to use a break in callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
    if ( bots.length > 0 ){
        if ( equal ){
            bots.sort( function(a,b){
                return a.getInventory().getItems().length - b.getInventory().getItems().length;
            });
        }
    var myMessages = [];
    //for(var i = 0; i < bots.length; i++){
        if ( bots[1].getInventory().getItems().length < capacity ){  
            var executed = false;
            bots[1].createDeposit({
                steamid: req.query.steamid,
                token: req.query.token,
                itemsFromThem: uniqueItems,
                message: req.query.message,
                callback: function( err, dbTradeId ){
                    if ( !executed ){
                        executed = true;
                        if ( !err && dbTradeId ){
                            res.json({ result: 1, dbTradeId: dbTradeId });
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            console.log('» Tried to create deposit, but',err);
                            myMessages.push("Problem");
                            res.json({ error: err });                   
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log('» Tried to create deposit, but no bot found(2)');
            myMessages.push("Available bot not found(2)");
        }
    //}
    } else {
        console.log('» Tried to create deposit, but no bot found');
        myMessages.push("Available bot not found"); 
    }
```

Short story, trying to loop through `bots` but I have a little problem with it. Exactly that if there will be a successful callback then I want it to stop the `for` loop but  I don't know how because I can't use there `break` or `return` the loop just keeps going. What could be the other solution for it? I also tried to add a variable `found = false` and then set it true, but for some reason it didn't work.

//Edit It was marked as duplicate, but it didn't help me at all.

Example:

```
0 - Error bot not available;
1 - Error bot not available;
2 - Error bot not available;
3 - Success and stop the loop;
```

Comment: That thread didn't help me at all. Could you please maybe help?

Comment: Can someone help me?